# DRD feature of USB type-C

Tags: usb, laptop, usb-c, connector

So I have got a laptop that has USB-C port and after some research I have got to know that it's got some feature called Dual Role Device i.e. it can act as both client as well as host device.
So why is it that I can't connect my old pc that has only USB type-A ports, which acts as host, to my new laptop, which acts as a device as it supports DRD, via a normal usb cable (USB-A to USB-C). I think that it should be doable with some software because appropriate hardware is available for the action.
Note: I am posting this question after quite reading many post including some of here. So it's a humble request to please don't suggest answers from other posts.

Comment: It may well be "doable with some software" but that depends on the software and OS supporting it. The only real documentation I can find suggests that the only Windows OS that got DRD was [Windows 10 Mobile on the ARM platform.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/dual-role-controller-bringup-for-a-usb-type-c-system) The only other system that I know supports DRD features is Android and while Android is Linux based it does not mean that Linux fully supports it as well. The switchable nature of DRD means that some kind of hardware driver support is required.

Comment: It would have been better to specify the laptop's model.

Comment: It's lenovo Ideapad Slim 3.

Comment: From where can I get the drivers required for that function.

Comment: The Linux drivers are part of the Linux kernel for a long time. Originally, the "direction" had to be chosen at compile time, but since Linux 3.10, it can be chosen at runtime.

Comment: Of course, you could forego the use of drivers and just program the chipset directly.

Comment: BTW, where did you find the information that the Lenovo Ideapad Slim 3 supports DRD? As far as I can tell, it just uses the standard USB controller that is part of the AMD chipset, and I can't find any confirmation that this chipset supports DRD.

Comment: Well I have intel i5 1235u

Comment: Then you should be accurate and say "Lenovo Ideapad Slim 3i"

Answer (score 0):

The Intel® Core™ i3-13x5U (Raptor Lake) provides Thunderbolt 4 on the Type-C port. To get the port role swap the link (both the cable and the host) should have extensive capabilities implemented/negotiated over Power Delivery protocol and TB4/USB4 functionality. The "normal usb cable (USB-A to USB-C)" nor your Type-A host port do not have anything closer to that, so no software will help here.